# How to solve $\frac{\partial{\rm B}}{\partial b}\left(0^+,1\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, special-functions, partial-derivative

Could you help me to prove

> $$\frac{\partial{\rm B}}{\partial b}\left(0^+,1\right)=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

where ${\rm B}(a,b)$ is Beta function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Knowing that
$$\text{B}\,(a,b)=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
and
$$\psi(x) =\frac{d}{dx} \ln{\Gamma(x)}= \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}\quad\Longrightarrow\quad\Gamma'(x)=\psi(x)\Gamma(x)$$
where $\Gamma(x)$ is [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and $\psi(x)$ is [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), then
$$\begin{align}\require\cancel\frac{\partial\text{B}}{\partial b}&=\frac{[\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)]'\cdot\Gamma(a+b)-\Gamma'(a+b)\cdot\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma^2(a+b)}\\&=\frac{[\Gamma'(a)\Gamma(b)+\Gamma(a)\Gamma'(b)]\Gamma(a+b)-\Gamma'(a+b)\cdot\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)\Gamma(a+b)}\\&=\frac{[0+\Gamma(a)\psi(b)\Gamma(b)]\cancel{\Gamma(a+b)}-\psi(a+b)\cancel{\Gamma(a+b)}\cdot\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)\cancel{\Gamma(a+b)}}\\&=\frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}\big[\psi(b)-\psi(a+b)\big]\\&=\text{B}\,(a,b)\big[\psi(b)-\psi(a+b)\big]\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial\text{B}}{\partial b}\left(0^+,1\right)&=\lim_{a\to0^+}\text{B}\,\left(a,1\right)\big[\psi(1)-\psi(a+1)\big]\\&=\lim_{a\to0^+}\frac{1}{a}\left[-\gamma+\gamma -\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\zeta (k+1)\;a^k\right]\tag{1}\\&=-\lim_{a\to0^+}\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}k\,\,\zeta (k+1)\;a^{k-1}\tag{2}\\&=-\lim_{a\to0^+}\left(\zeta(2)-2\zeta(3)a+3\zeta(4)a^2-4\zeta(5)a^3+\cdots\right)\tag{3}\\&=-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\tag{4}\end{align}$$

---

**Explanation :**
$(1)$ Use series representations of $\displaystyle\text{B}\,\left(x,1\right)=\frac{1}{x}$ and $\displaystyle\psi(x+1)=-\gamma +\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\zeta (k+1)\;x^k$ for $|x|<1$
$(2)$ Use [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) because of indeterminate form $\dfrac{0}{0}$
$(3)$ Expanding the series form
$(4)$ Use $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: A perfect answer!Thank you very much,venus.

Comment: @gcy-rolle You're welcome. I'm glad I can help.

Comment: @Integrator I know that but I'm afraid the OP will ask the proof of it, so that's why I add the details

Comment: @Integrator That's good. It's OK for me.

Comment: Or, even better, use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula). Its proof relies on differentiating the natural logarithm of the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties).

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{#c00000}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{a\ >\ 0}$ and $\ds{b\ >\ 0}$:

> $$
> {\rm B}\pars{a,b}\equiv\int_{0}^{1}t^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{b - 1}\,\dd t
> $$

$$
\partiald{{\rm B}\pars{a,b}}{b}
=\int_{0}^{1}t^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{b - 1}\ln\pars{1 - t}\,\dd t
$$

> \begin{align}
> \left.\partiald{{\rm B}\pars{a,b}}{b}\right\vert_{\, b\ =\ 1}
> &=\int_{0}^{1}t^{a - 1}\ln\pars{1 - t}\,\dd t
> =\int_{0}^{1}t^{a - 1}\bracks{-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{t^{n} \over n}}\,\dd t
> \\[5mm]&=-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n}\int_{0}^{1}t^{n + a - 1}\,\dd t
> =-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n\pars{n + a}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#66f}{\large%
\lim_{a\ \to\ 0^{+}}\left.\partiald{{\rm B}\pars{a,b}}{b}\right\vert_{\, b\ =\ 1}}
=-\sum_{n\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{2}}
=\color{#66f}{\large -\,{\pi^{2} \over 6}}
$$

Comment: awesome! Thank you for your detailed answer,@Felix Marin.

Comment: This is much easier than my answer. Nice answer Felix (+1)

Comment: @Venus Thanks. Just a different point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another slightly different approach.

As Venus showed in her answer, the partial derivative of the beta function $\text{B} (a,b)$ with respect to $b$ is 
$$\partial_b \text{B}(a,b) = \text{B} (a,b) \left [\psi (b) - \psi (a + b) \right ],$$
where $\psi (x)$ is the digamma function.

When evaluated at $b = 1$ we have
$$\partial_b \text{B} (a,b) \Big{|}_{b = 1} = \text{B} (a,1) \left [\psi (1) - \psi (1 + a) \right ].$$
Now observe that
$$\text{B} (a,1) = \frac{\Gamma (a) \Gamma (1)}{\Gamma (a + 1)} = \frac{\Gamma (a)}{a \Gamma (a)} = \frac{1}{a}.$$
Thus
$$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \partial_b \text{B} (a,1) \Big{|}_{b = 1} = \lim_{a \to 0^+} \frac{\psi (1) - \psi(1 + a)}{a}.$$
The limit is indeterminate and of the form $\frac{0}{0}$. So for its evaluation we may apply l'Hôpital's rule. Doing so yields
$$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \partial_b \text{B} (a,1) \Big{|}_{b = 1} = \lim_{a \to 0^+} -\psi^{(1)}(1 + a) = -\psi^{(1)}(1),$$
where we note the derivative of the digamma function $\psi (a)$ gives the first order [polygamma gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function) (or trigamma) function $\psi^{(1)} (a)$.

We now find the value for $\psi^{(1)} (1)$. The polygamma function of order $m$ is defined by
$$\psi^{(m)} (z) = (-1)^{m + 1} m! \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{(z + n)^{m + 1}}.$$
To find the value of $\psi^{(1)}(1)$, setting $m = 1$ and $z = 1$ gives
$$\psi^{(1)} (1) = \sum^\infty_{n = 0} \frac{1}{(n + 1)^2}.$$
Shifting the index in the sum by $n \mapsto n - 1$ gives
$$\psi^{(1)}(1) = \sum^\infty_{n = 1} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi}{6},$$
the sum corresponding to the very famous [Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

So finally for our limit we have
$$\lim_{a \to 0^+} \partial_b \text{B} (a,1) \Big{|}_{b = 1} = - \frac{\pi^2}{6},$$
as required.